# What does a new Muslim need to know when fasting?

Tags: sawm

I am thinking of fasting (voluntary).  Can anyone tell me all things I need to know because I am a new Muslim I do not know anything? Tell me everything like when I can eat, when I can not eat and how to manage prayer and everything else please.  Can I eat/drink at the end of fajr (sunrise)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The essential part of an Islamic fast is to not eat, drink or satisfy sexual desire during the day; with the conscious intention of observing a fast.

The day starts at **astronomical dawn** and ends at **sunset**. You must stop eating at dawn and not eat again till sunset.

Its sunnah to eat a little just before the start of the fast (called *Suhoor* ). The fast is concluded (called *Iftar*) with a meal or water at sunset. You can eat, drink etc. through the night.

> #### وكلوا واشربوا حتى يتبين لكم الخيط الأبيض من الخيط الأسود من الفجر ثم أتموا الصيام إلى الليل
>
> And eat and drink until the white thread of dawn becomes distinct to you from the black thread [of night]. Then complete the fast until the night (sunset)
>
> <sup>— [Quran 2:187](https://quran.com/2/187)</sup>

---

The exact starting and ending times vary depending on your location and time of the year, you may use a website where you type in your location and it calculates the time for you, e.g:

- http://www.islamicity.org/PrayerTimes/ (use starting time of Fajr and the time for Maghrib)
- https://www.islamicfinder.org/ (same as above)
- https://www.timeanddate.com/sun/ (use starting time for astronomical twilight and the time of sunset)

You may also find apps for location aware devices which do the same thing.

Comment: Can I eat until sun do not rise or I can not eat just after starting fajr time

Comment: @Anonykous You immediately stop eating at ***dawn***, which is the **starting** time of fajr, and happens hours before sunrise. Use a website or app to get the exact time for astronomical dawn or Fajr for your location. A mosque near you may also help.